Find $\sum_{i=0}^n 7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)^2$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n 7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)^2$$
It just happens so that I knew this series is a telescopic with $$\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)^7 - i^7 - 1$$
But how can I deduce from the top sequence that it is forming a telescopic sum?

Uptill now from what questions I've solved, telescoping series require a difference in the infinite sum. Usually in case of rational functions, we can do partial fractional decomposition. Here in this case you'll have to bring out a difference somehow

Just mutiplying out $7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)^2$ and seeing that it is almost the Binomial expansion of $(i+1)^{7}$ is one way.

@Gwen Telescopic works for finite sum as well whether it's in rational form or like the above

@geetha290krm I think that's the only way to go about this sequence. If you have some idea of binomial coefficients then expanding the terms have almost every term of $(i+1)^7$ except $i^7$ and $1$.

By the way, the sequence is a particular case of $7xy(x+y)(x^2 +xy + y^2)^2$

You can compare the roots and double roots.

Not an answer. A nice observation...
Let $p_1(x)=7x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)^2$ and $p_2(x)=(x+1)^7-x^7-1.$
We have that $x_1=0, x_2=-1, x_3=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$ and $x_4=e^{\frac{4\pi i}3}$ are the roots of these polynomials. Furthermore, $x_3$ and $x_4$ are double roots: $(x+1)^6=x^6$ for them.
Since the leading coefficients of these polynomials are $7$, $p_1(x)=p_2(x)$.

The question is "I don't know about $p_2(x)$, I can even imagine the rewriting of $p_1$ as $p_2$?"

@VincenzoTibullo In comments geetha290krm gave a simple way for solution. I did not want to write his way. İ know $p_2$ is not given. I just noticed that roots are interesting.

@VincenzoTibullo I cant see the tricky solution you have in mind. İ am not expert on cyclotomic polynomials.

I have no tricky solution in mind, I just noted that this does not answer the OP question, at least compared with how I understood the question

I agree with @VincenzoTibullo . We don’t already know about $p_2(x)$. It’s not what I am looking for
